# Выведите чекбокс, который при каждом запуске программы случайным образом должен быть либо включенным, либо выключенным

Tags: python, tkinter

Выведите чекбокс, который при каждом запуске программы случайным образом должен быть либо включенным, либо выключенным.
Я 3 день занимаюсь тока в Python так что не ругайте, я догнать не могу как это сделать понимаю что то с модулем random надо делать а куда его вставлять не пойму все перепробовал подскажите как сделать

```
import random
from tkinter import *


def setwindow(root):
    root.title('Окно программы')
    root.resizable(False, False)
    w = 800  # Размер ширины окна
    h = 600  # Размер высоты окна
    # Теперь надо узнать размер экрана пользователя
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()  # тоесть информация размера экна по ширине
    wh = root.winfo_screenheight()  # размер экна по длинне

    x = int(ws / 2 - w / 2)  # преобразуем их сразу к целому типу (делим размера экрана по ширине  на размер окна и получаем левый верхний угол
    y = int(wh / 2 - h / 2)  # Делим размер экрана по длинне на размер высоты окна
    root.geometry('{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}'.format(w, h, x, y))
root = Tk()#для того чтоб создать окно нужно вызвать конструктор данного модуля tkinter
setwindow(root)#вызов функции setwindow

choice = IntVar()#Чтоб узнать кликнули по данному чекбоксу или нет нужно восподльзоваться IntVar() в отдельной переменной он обарачивает как бы переменную  в оболочку с которой можно работать как с переменной но с помощью спец методов
#например так изменим значение choice.set(10)
#например так получим значение choice.get
#И мы должны данный checkbuttun превезать к данной переменной делается это с помощью параметра variable = и указываем переменную
#Далее нужно указать какие должны быть установлены значения если чекбокс включон и выключен для вкл параметр onvalue,для вык offvalue
check = Checkbutton(root,bd='20',text='чекбокс',variable=choice,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)#чекбокс это окошко где ставится галочка
a = check.select()
b = check.deselect()

check.pack()

#heck.select()#так можно включить флажек
#check.deselect()#так можно снять флажек

print(choice.get())#Так проверяем вкл или выключен флажек

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Сгенерируйте, например, случайное целое число от 0 до 1. Если оно будет равным единицы, то включите чекбокс. Иначе, выключите. Посмотрите на функцию [`random.randint`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/random.randint/).

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку все заработало)

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам исходный код

```
from tkinter import *


def setwindow(root):
    root.title('Окно программы')
    root.resizable(False, False)
    w = 800
    h = 600
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    wh = root.winfo_screenheight()

    x = int(ws / 2 - w / 2)
    y = int(wh / 2 - h / 2)
    root.geometry('{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}'.format(w, h, x, y))
root = Tk()
choice = IntVar()
ch = int(random.choice([0,1]))
if ch == 1:
    print(check.select())
else:
    print(check.deselect())
  
check = Checkbutton(root,bd=20,text='чекбокс',variable=choice,onvalue=ch)

root.mainloop()
```